# How do I create a list of generic delegate instances?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to create a collection of factory methods that can instantiate various objects, whose type will only be known at run time. I can easily create a delegate for this:

```
delegate T InstanceCreator<T>()
```

but this gives a compiler error: "cannot resolve symbol T"

```
Dictionary<string, InstanceCreator<T>>
```

so in place of this I just declare

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate>
```

I tried to make up for this lack of type specificity in the Add method but run into the same problem.

```
public void AddFactory(string typeName, InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

Is there a better way to to ensure that only `InstanceCreator<T>` delegates get added to my collection?

Comment: We need to see more code. Specifically, could you show us the actual code where you are attempting to create the generic objects or call the generic functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make AddFactory a generic method:

```
public void AddFactory<T>(string typeName, InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

This will constrain it to only allowing `InstanceCreator<T>` elements to be added.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AddFactory(string typeName,InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

Where is `T` coming from?  You need to make the method itself generic for this to work:

```
public void AddFactory<T>(string typeName,InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `AddFactory` a generic method:

```
public void AddFactory<T>(string typeName, InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this....

```
public void AddFactory<T>(string typeName,InstanceCreator<T> factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass generic type parameter through the class or method.

I would suggest using standard [Func< TResult >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) generic delegate:

**Class generic type parameter:**

```
public class FactoryRepository<T>
{
  IDictionary<string, Func<T>> factoryCache;

  public FactoryRepository()
  {
      this.factoryCache = new Dictionary<string, Func<T>>();
  }

  public void AddFactory(string key, Func<T> factory)
  {   
      this.factoryCache.Add(key, factory);
  }
}
```

**Method generic type parameter:**

```
public void AddFactory<T>(string key, Func<T> factory)
{
      // IDictionary<string, Func<T>> factoryCache
      factoryCache.Add(key, factory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At what scope are you declaring the delegate.

```
delegate T InstanceCreator<T>()
```

If its at the namespace level the T you are suing there and T you are using in your method are not the same. Declare the delegate in the scope of the class and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have `typeName` as a string, I would suggest having a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` and use it something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> factories = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

public void AddFactory<T>(InstanceCreator<T> factory)
{
    factories.Add(typeof(T), factory);
}

public InstanceCreator<T> GetFactory()
{
   return (InstanceCreator<T>)factories[typeof(T)];
}
```

Also, there is no need to create your own delegate types, `Func<T>` would work just as well.